# Why is it creating a bound method and how to fix it?

Tags: python

When I manually call deal method it works but when under while playing it creates a bound method.
Any ideas to fix it.

```
import  random

#Raw values

suits = ("Hearts","Diamonds","Spades","Clubs")
ranks = ("Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King","Ace")
values = {"Two":2,"Three":3,"Four":4,"Five":5,"Six":6,"Seven":7,"Eight":8,"Nine":9,"Ten":10,"Jack":10,"Queen":10,"King":10,"Ace":11}

playing = True
```

Classes are defined here

```
#Define classes

class Card:

    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + " of " + self.suit


class Deck:

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit,rank))

    def __str__(self):
        deck_comp = ""
        for card in self.deck:
            deck_comp += " \n " + card.__str__()
        return "The deck has" + deck_comp

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def deal(self):
        single_card = self.deck.pop()
        return single_card
```

Hand class for the creating the hands for players

```
class Hand:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.value = 0
        self.ace = 0

    def add_card(self,card):
        self.cards.append(card)
        self.value += values[card.rank]
        if card.rank == "Ace":
            self.ace += 1

    def adjust_for_ace(self):
        while self.value >21 and self.ace>0:
            self.value -= 10
            self.ace -= 1
```

Functions are made here

```
#Functions to use during play

def Take_bet(chips):

    while True:
        try:
            chips.bet = int(input("Enter your bet:"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Bet must be in integer form")
        else:
            if chips.bet>chips.chip:
                print("Bet is outside ",chips.chip)
            else:
                break
```

Hit function is mainly creating the bound method problem

```
def Hit(deck,hand):
    hand.add_card(deck.deal)
    hand.adjust_for_ace()

def Hit_or_stand(deck,hand):
    global playing

    while True:    
        x = input("Would you like hit or stand(enter 'h' or 's'):")

        if x[0].lower()=='h':
            Hit(deck,hand)

        elif x[0].lower()=='s':
            playing = False

        else:
            print("Please try again.")
            continue
        break

while True:
    print("Welcome to Blackjack! Get as close to 21 as possible without going over\n The dealer hits until it reaches 17.Aces count as 1 or 11")

    deck = Deck()
    deck.shuffle()
```

Manually calling the deal method successfully creates an instance of card class

```
player_hand = Hand()
player_hand.add_card(deck.deal())
player_hand.add_card(deck.deal())

dealer_hand = Hand()
dealer_hand.add_card(deck.deal())
dealer_hand.add_card(deck.deal())

player_chips = Chips()

Take_bet(player_chips)

show_some(player_hand,dealer_hand)

while playing:
    '''
    card instance creates a bound method
    '''
    Hit_or_stand(deck,player_hand)

    show_some(player_hand,dealer_hand)
```

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bitan\Desktop\Programs\Python\blackjack.py", line 153, in <module>
    Hit_or_stand(deck,player_hand)
  File "C:\Users\bitan\Desktop\Programs\Python\blackjack.py", line 94, in Hit_or_stand
    Hit(deck,hand)
  File "C:\Users\bitan\Desktop\Programs\Python\blackjack.py", line 84, in Hit
    hand.add_card(deck.deal)
  File "C:\Users\bitan\Desktop\Programs\Python\blackjack.py", line 49, in add_card
    self.value += values[card.rank]
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'rank'              I posted part of code only

Comment: deck.deal *always* creates a bound method. The difference is whether you call it or not. In Hit, you don’t.

Comment: Please take note that your code volume is extreme, with most of it being entirely unrelated to your problem and not necessary to reproduce the problem. Please take a look at the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the `Hit` function, you are trying to add a card to a hand but are passing the method `deck.deal` rather than the result of a call to `deck.deal()`

```
def Hit(deck,hand):
    hand.add_card(deck.deal())  # <- here
    hand.adjust_for_ace()
```

Comment: This worked in while true where I tried manually adding instead of function

Comment: In the original post,after while true I add_card two time for player and dealer hands